# How can I replace a CSS border in HTML using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm following a simple web development tutorial and would like to have an interactive border depending on the outcome of Rock, Paper, Scissors. How can I replace (or overlay) the current CSS border of the Rock, Paper, or Scissor images?

According to the tutorial the solution is as shown in the code. However, this is the result that I am getting: https://ibb.co/wBFG2cQ (Sorry, I'm not allowed to embed images directly). Here is the intended outcome: https://ibb.co/tB7HvWX. Lastly, a link to the website hosted on a free hosting site where all source code is viewable https://rockpaperscissors-ndsamu.netlify.com/.

JavaScript Code (last 2 lines):

```
function win(userChoice, computerChoice) {
    userScore++;
    userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
    result_p.innerHTML = `${convertToWord(userChoice)} beats ${convertToWord(computerChoice)}. You win!`;
    document.getElementById('crown').style.left="-100px";
    document.getElementById('crown').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById(userChoice).classList.add('green-glow');
    setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById(userChoice).classList.remove('green-glow') }, 1000);
}
```

CSS Code (for each image):

```
.choice {
    border: 4px solid #25272E;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

CSS Code (for Winning):

```
.green-glow {
    border: 4px solid #4DCC7D;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #3DA364;
}
```

Instead, I would like the green circular border to replace or overlay the current border rather than appearing within it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? Anyway, it looks like you're applying the green border to the image, not the container element.

Comment: seems like you are adding the class to the wrong element.... Hard to tell with what is provided.

Comment: @ndsamu can you post some of the html code please? i.e where the element with id 'crown' is and the element with class "choice" etc.

Comment: Apologies for the newbie mistakes - I am hosting on a free hosting site here where I believe you can see the full source code: https://rockpaperscissors-ndsamu.netlify.com/

Comment: Looking at the page confirms what I said in my first comment. You're adding the class to the img, not the div.

Comment: Much appreciated, Chris. With that in mind, how can I access the "choice" class without adding to all of the choices?

Comment: @ndsamu yes Chris is right. Ive just tested the code and if you add the green-glow to its parent (i.e the div with choice class) then it works. You can do this as follows:   document.getElementById(userChoice).parentElement.classList.add('green-glow');

Comment: Thank you, Sarah! I had also solved by adding an ID of Rock, Paper, and Scissor to the parent class but I think you have a much more convenient/elegant solution there. I'll switch that over now!

Comment: @ndsamu No probs. Glad it worked out for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your full code, It's hard to tell what's causing that. My best guess is `padding: 15px` is the culprit. If it is, then Maybe try adding `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` to your CSS and see if that fixes things.

Here's some code that shows how to do what they are doing, it's been simplified. You can activate a circle by clicking on it.

```js
function win(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  document.getElementById(userChoice).classList.add("green-glow");
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById(userChoice).classList.remove("green-glow");
  }, 1000);
}

// seimple way to pick a random element
document.getElementById("choice1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  win("choice1", "");
});
document.getElementById("choice2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  win("choice2", "");
});
document.getElementById("choice3").addEventListener("click", function() {
  win("choice3", "");
});
```

```css
.row {
  display: block;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 4px solid #25272e;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.circle.green-glow {
  border: 4px solid #4dcc7d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #3da364;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="choice1" class="circle">
  </div>
  <div id="choice2" class="circle">
  </div>
  <div id="choice3" class="circle">
  </div>
</div>
```